I need help to combined two swaps in one transaction like a bundle on jupiter api, I always got Transaction too large error
What I did is, get the quotes from two swaps using jupiter api, then make the quotes as swap instructions and bundle it together like this:
// Combine both swap instructions into a single transaction
const combinedTx = new Transaction().add(...instruction1, ...instruction2);
const { blockhash: blockhash1 } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
combinedTx.recentBlockhash = blockhash1;
combinedTx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

// Sign and send the transaction
const signaturetx = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  combinedTx,
  [wallet],
  { commitment: "confirmed", preflightCommitment: "processed" }
);

